# Codename One Container in Y-Layout not scrolling when using UIID

Tags: java, codenameone

I am preparing an Android app that is using a container in Boxlayout.y.

When using the code example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056010/codename-one-boxlayout-scroll) , scrolling the container content in x-direction works beautifully.

But when I change the code to use a y-layout, the container loses its ability to scroll and scrolls only when I tap on the  form and outside the container or not on any components inside.

Interestingly, the problem with y-scroll only surges when I add a UIID to the container.

```
Container containerBase = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Form formSelect = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
int[] colors = { 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xff0000ff, 0xff000000 };
    
containerBase.setScrollableY(true);

containerBase.setUIID("ContainerBase");  `culprit seems to be here`  

for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 100 ; iter++) {
        
    containerBase.add(new Button(Image.createImage(100, 50, colors[iter % colors.length]), "test"));

}
```

I am missing something?

I am on Arch, using Eclipse and Maven.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is nested scrolling which is only supported for different axis. On desktop apps you can put a scrollbar anywhere but Codename One doesn't support that.

On touch devices you can swipe any component in the hierarchy to scroll in a specific direction. If you have two scrollable Y containers one within the other we have no way of knowing which one to scroll. It also makes size calculations impossible due to the way scrolling works.

Since the parent form is scrollable on the Y axis by default, you don't need to make the child containers scrollable. They will scroll implicitly. Notice that a `BorderLayout` implicitly disables scrolling on a `Form` and using that will workaround the issue.

Also removing `containerBase.setScrollableY(true);` will work too.

Comment: perfect solution, many thanks